# SublimeText3 Selected Lines Reverse Order

Tags: text, line, reverse

I wonder is there a way to REVERSE THE LINE ORDER for instance

from this:

```
Line 5
Line 4
Line 3
Line 2
Line 1
```

to:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but yes, there is: Select the amount of lines you want to reverse and click

<kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Permute Lines</kbd> > <kbd>Reverse</kbd>.